# Retrieving text out of a tag , with ng repeat and a class attribute gives empty/undefined element using protractor

Tags: angularjs, testing, protractor

I have the angular page source code that looks like below.

```html
<ul>
<li class = classname1>
 <a ui-sref="name1()" href="/_">Name1</a>==$0
 </li>
<li class = classname1>
 <a>Name2</a>
 <div class="classname2">
  <!--ng-repeat: dropDown in belownames.getDropdownList('Name2')-->
  <a ng-repeat="dropDown in belownames.getDropdownList('Name2')" ui-sref="Name3Data()"
  class="ng-binding ng-scope" href="Name3Data">Name3</a>
  <!--end ngrepeat: dropDown in n belownames.getDropdownList('Name2')-->
  <a ng-repeat="dropDown in belownames.getDropdownList('Name2')" ui-sref="Name4Data()"
  class="ng-binding ng-scope" href="Name4Data">Name4</a>
  <!--end ngrepeat: dropDown in n belownames.getDropdownList('Name2')-->
  <a ng-repeat="dropDown in belownames.getDropdownList('Name2')" ui-sref="Name5Data()"
  class="ng-binding ng-scope" href="Name5Data">Name5</a>
  <!--end ngrepeat: dropDown in n belownames.getDropdownList('Name2')-->
  </div>
 </li> 
<li class = classname1></li>
<li class = classname1></li>
</ul>>
```

I want to extract elements/links under each of the a tags namely,

```
1.Name3
2.Name4
3.Name5
```

And then click on those links to go insert some data in there.

I have tried using below test in my it block

```
    element.all(by.repeater("dropDown in belownames.getDropdownList('Name2')")).getText().then(function(value)
{
    console.log(value);
})
```

However i get the output as array of null values

```
[ '', '', '' ]
```

How Do I resolve this? Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.
mnc

Answer (score 0):

Could you please try like this . Extract the text for each element

```
    element.all(by.repeater("dropDown in belownames.getDropdownList('Name2')")).then(function(elements)
{

elements.forEach(function(element){
element.getText().then(function(text){
console.log(text);
});
});
})
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I tried the above snippet. It still did not display the text. Test passed though.   One thing I forgot to mention, is the fact that these drop down elements on my page, are only visible when I hover my mouse over them. Do I need to write a mouseOver function then before displaying the individual element's text?

Comment: As per my knowledge it is not required to mouseOver on the element if the code for it is visible in the DOM.

Comment: Also, In your comment you have mentioned that Test is passed, what was the error  you were getting before